# Zend Navigation add extra id

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-navigation

I made a menu with zend_navigation, using an ini file.
That work well. If I look at the code, i see that zend has added a class, to the ul element.

With a name that i use in my ini file. 
But now I want to add also a id to the ul element.
How can I do this?

```
protected function _initNavigation()
{
    $this->bootstrap('layout');
    $layout = $this->getResource('layout');
    $view   = $layout->getView();

    $iniOptions = array('allowModifications' => true);
    $config = new Zend_Config_Ini(APPLICATION_PATH . '/configs/navigation.ini', 'nav', $iniOptions);
    $config->id = 1;        

    $navigation = new Zend_Navigation($config->navigation);        
    $view->navigation($navigation);
}
```

Comment: Have you tried adding your custom property to $navigation instead of $config? $navigation->id = 1;

Answer (score 0):

I use Zend_Navigation as well but define mine in XML. I was able to add an foo node next to my label, module, controller, and route. The result was the addition of an "id" attribute and the value being "menu-foo".

Can you add the "id to your navigation.ini directly?

Comment: I've tried that, but it does not work.
Does anyone have an idea whether it is possible with an ini file?

Answer (score 0):

i can do this:
Then i have an id on the li element, but not on the ul element.

```
[nav]
navigation.home.id = 1
navigation.home.label = Home
navigation.home.controller = index
navigation.home.action = indexter code here`
```

output:

```
<ul class="navigation">
    <li>

        <a id="menu-1" href="/">Home</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```